# Download an Entire Directory Using FTP4J

Tags: java, ftp4j

I have looked through the documentation and I can't seem to find a function which does this. So, I assume that I should code it myself. Looking further into the documentation, I found a list() function which lists all the files in a working directory. How would I download all the files while preserving the directory structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you connect to the server:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect(host);
client.login(user, pass);
```

> You change to the desired folder

```
client.changeDirectory(ftpFolder);
```

and then you request the list of files:

```
FTPFile[] list = client.list();
```

Iterate the file array of results and download the file.
using:

```
FTPFile[] list = client.list();
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
   //client.download("localFile", new java.io.File("remotefile);
    client.download(list[i].getName(), new java.io.File(list[i].getName());    
}
```

Comment: Ah, you're a grave digger. Thank you very much.